# mongoose/typegoose db with multiple collections

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, typegoose

How do I set up a mongoose/typegoose connection with multiple collections?

```
class Onboarding {
  @prop({ index: true, required: true })
  date: string;
}

class Metrics {
  @prop({ index: true, required: true })
  date: string;
}


MetricsUtil.MetricsModel = getModelForClass(Metrics, {
          existingMongoose: mongoose,
          schemaOptions: { collection: 'metrics' },
        });
    
        MetricsUtil.OnboardingModel = getModelForClass(Onboarding, {
          existingMongoose: mongoose,
          schemaOptions: { collection: 'onboarding' },
        });
        await mongoose.connect(uri, options);
```

When I initialize the db, it only creates the collection 'metrics' and not 'onboarding'.

And when I try to write something to the onboarding collection, "MetricsUtil.OnboardingModel.findOneAndUpdate" , it writes to the 'metrics' collection.

Not sure what I'm missing here. Been trying to find examples on how to set this up.

Comment: mongoose only creates collections when first writing an model, and typegoose uses the class name (lower cased) as the model name and mongoose uses the model name as collection name (in plural if not already) if not provided otherwise ---
you should maybe set the collection for your `Metrics` class to something different, because mongodb might use such an collection internally